# R to $R^{20}$ linear transformation for classification?

Tags: transformation, machine-learning

I try to do some type of classification.I have **2 timeseries signals** to distinguish from eachother.

Here is the way i was told to do it:
I take into account one of these signals and call it MySignal hereforth.
I place a 20-sample consecuitive window on this signal and then these 20 values will be considered as elements of a vector of 20-Dimension(MyVector).
In this way i do a **mapping** from R to $R^{20}$ 
so if MySignal has 200 points, we will have 10 MyVector vectors.Therefore in $R^{20}$ space we will have 10 points which creats a 20_window **signal**.

I repeat the same action for the second timeserie signal and plot both 20_window signals in $R^{20}$ space. then I feed a decision tree algorithm with these two 20_window signals. 
if these two timeseries signals are not distinguishable from each other in **R** space by a **straight line**, can they be distinguishable in $R^{20}$ by a **straight line** parallel to any of 20 axes?

Let me clarify what i'm doing. After creating these 20_sample signals, i feed them to a decision tree (WEKA) which creates a very small decision tree.
I try to understand how this decision tree is created (meaning how these test functions in each node  are created by this tree).

btw, is there any **keyword** that i can use to look for this type of Transformation from R to $R^{20}$ without entering to the concept of Decision trees or Classification I mean by **mathematics**?

Thanks

Comment: Do your texts employ eccentric random boldfacing of terms? It is pretty distracting...

Comment: so you suggest not to use boldface in text?

Comment: Well some general rules of thumb would be to not use boldface for every instance of a particular word, and to not use boldface for mundane words like "mathematics".